# Model design for a user who can have roles at multiple organizations

Tags: python, django, database-design, django-models, django-guardian

I need a Django model where a `User` can have a `Function` with any number of `Organisations`. His permissions (change, view, delete) with the organization are determined by his `Role`. I am pretty sure I only need an "admin" and a "member" role.

This would require row-level permissions, so I decided to go with django-guardian. I am having trouble choosing the proper model design. These are the alternatives

[image]

**The first one** would have the advantage of creating new roles, but I don't think I need that. Also I can enforce `unique_together` so that a User can only have 1 function at every company. Would I set the `can_change` permission at the `Role` and infer the row level permission based on the relation between `User` and `Organization`? The would mean I do not even need django-guardian, right?

**The second one** looks much simpler, but maybe that is deceptive. The permissions would have to be set as soon as a `User` is added to an `Organization` and are definitely row-level.

What is the right strategy here?

To clarify: in both cases a user can be an admin of one organization and simply a member of another organization.

Comment: My question is sadly not getting any responses. Please do comment if you think it can be improved or should be asked somewhere else.

Comment: I found it exceedingly hard to implement it with `django-guardian`, so I started developing `django-trusts`. It does not solve your problem per se, but untangle the organizations model from a permissions models might make it more doable. With `django-trusts`, you can assign a trust base on his organization role.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Party Model.

A user is not a person, it's a user. Person and organization are parties. A party hasOne (or no) user.

A person hasMany (many2many) relationships with an organization:

Individual -< Relationship >- Organization

Organizations can have relationships with each other too.

Comment: That is a new and interesting concept for me to digest. I quickly took it in, but it looks like my application has some aspects that are less than suited for the Party Model. Some of the data will be highly hierarchical / relational and perfectly suited for a conventional model. I rely heavily on ORM and I like having meaningful object names to make sense of relationships. Finally I think that the added flexibility will ever be needed and the patterns above would suffice. I know that is a bold claim to make. Please let me know if I misunderstand the Party Model (as it is new to me).

Comment: @RoyPrins most relationships are really network/graphical, not hierarchical. For example, a person could work for two companies, or could be both a customer and supplier. ORMs like hibernate work well with the Party model (use @Inheritance). Most companies sell to both individuals and organizations, so the Party model is kind required in that case. See data modeling books by Silverston and Hay.

Comment: Look like I downvoted your answer by accident, but stackoverflow doesn't allow me to fix it now because it was "voted within the last 24 hours". Sorry about that.

Comment: @Thomas-BeeDesk corrected it with an extra upvote ;)

Comment: @gabn88, stackoverflow now says i cannot do it because the vote was made too long ago...